# stored procedure, show values from two tables with foreign key

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables, vehicles and distance, and would like to show luggage _capacity and seating_capacity when I execute procedure with source_town, source_state, dest_town, and dest_state. Distances table have foreign key ( vehicles_id).

this is what I have so far

```
create or replace procedure availabe_ride (
s_town varchar2,
s_state varchar2,
d_town varchar2,
d_state varchar2,
l_capacity number,
s_capacity number)

is 
begin
select source_town, source_state, dest_town, dest_state, luggage_capacity, seating_capacity
into s_town, s_state, d_town, d_state, l_capacity, s_capacity
from vehicles v, distances d
where v.vehicles_id = d.vehicles_id;
```

I can't fogure out how to do this...
please help...

Comment: You need to edit your question and include the table definitions, sample data, and expected output.